Getting Perl File::Tail to begin streaming a file towards the end
I am using the code below to continuously read from a file. The problem I am having is that whenever I run the code it starts at the beginning of the file, returning the entire file, instead of starting at the last 50 lines.
I have consulted the documentation and tried different values for the tail=>n argument-- even n=total lines in the file minus 50-- however my code begins every time at the start of the the file instead of at the end like I need. What am I doing wrong?
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Tail;
my $name; #file name

my $name="/home/richard/double-take/messages.log";
my $line;
my $file=File::Tail->new(name=>$name, interval=>3, maxinterval=>3, tail=>50);

while (defined($line=$file->read)) {

    print "$line";
}


File::Tail is up to date.  (1.3)

I just tried it they way you have it (w/o interval=>3, maxinterval=>3,) and now it works.

It is apparently cause by the maxinterval argument. When I add that argument back it returns the whole file.

You didn't accurately describe what happens. What actually happens is that it displays the last 50 lines as desired. But 30 seconds later, it displays the entire file. This happens whether you set maxinterval or not. It just takes longer if you don't. Specifically, it takes resetafter after seconds, and that defaults to adjustafter*maxinterval, and adjustafter defaults to 10.

Doesn't seem to happen without tail, so appears to be a bug.

If you say it happens whether I set the maxinterval or not then how do prevent if from happening?

Like I said, might be a bug. So contacting the author would be a good start

I wonder if it's the same bug as this one, which has a patch

Yes, applying that patch fixed the problem.

Author of File::Tail here.
File::Tail tries to be clever when the file it is reading has not been updated for a while, it checks it at longer and longer intervals (configurable with maxinterval), because there's no point in doing a busy-wait on a file that is not being written to. After the having waited for adjustafter * maxinterval, File::Tail decides that the file may have been rotated out from under it. (You can also change this with the parameter resetafter).
Many of the logfiles that File::Tail users read are configured to rotate in one way or another. Some rotate by closing the file, renaming it, and then writing to a new file with the original name. To cope with that, after the set interval, File::Tail tries re-opening the file.
The question is, when it re-opens the file, from where should it read it? Most common use-cases need different handling for when the file is re-opened as opposed to being opened the first time. So File::Tail has a special parameter for how it should handle the file after reopening, it's called reset_tail.
By default it is set to -1 (give me the whole file), because that is the most common use-case i.e. "I am reading and analysing this file, so after a rotate happens, I want to see all the lines that I missed while I was looking at the old file". But if you don't want to see the whole file after re-open, just set reset_tail to 0, or a positive integer.
I can't comment on the fix proposed by ikegami, it's been many years since  I wrote that code, and I need to review it and re-grok it before I can say with confidence that it fits in with the rest of the code.
I'll try to release a new version, with even more documentation fixes warning you about the different parameters you can tweak, and possibly with an added "ignore-same-inode" parameter, for when the engineer using File::Tail is confident the file in question will be rotated, and not simply over-written.

Thank you for writing the module in the first place. I am using it to monitor my patio for unidentified people from my Fridgate->Double-take->Compreface stack so it is helping provide security for myself and family.
